# Как в запросе вывести повторяющиеся записи со значениями NULL в некоторых столбцах?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть готовая выборка данных, вывод которой выглядит так:

```
    cчет                 пластик     дебит     кредит
    -------------------- ---------- ------ ----------
    40812345658564500001 dhgfhsd      2131       3131
    40812345658564500002 shsrhhrsh    2354   35345435
**  40812345658564500003 srrsebghn     125         60
**  40812345658564500003 srghhtsrt     125         60
    40812345658564500004 hthwgwrwg  657567     567567
    40812345658564500005 wrwgwrg    756757     567567
```

Проблема в том, что есть строки в которых дублируются счета. Т.е. прошел перевыпуск карты, счет остался, а пластик поменялся. Дебит и кредит также совпадают.

Мне необходимо обработать эту выборку так, чтобы у таких строк (выделенных **) с одинаковым счетом первая строка осталась без изменения, а все последующие строки для этого счета не имели дебета и кредита, чтобы можно было корректно просуммировать. Вообще, удалять лишние строки нельзя, информация по пластику должна остаться.

Как это можно сделать?

У меня получился такой запрос, он работает, но выглядит как-то очень сложно:

```sql
WITH 
T1 AS(SELECT * FROM rabota), --все
T2 AS(SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE accnt_acnt IN (SELECT accnt_acnt --дубли
                                              FROM T1
                                             GROUP BY accnt_acnt
                                            HAVING COUNT(accnt_acnt) > 1)),
T3 AS(SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE accnt_acnt NOT IN (SELECT accnt_acnt --без дублей
                                                  FROM T1
                                                 GROUP BY accnt_acnt
                                                HAVING COUNT(accnt_acnt) > 1)),
T4 AS(SELECT row_number() over(partition BY accnt_acnt ORDER BY accnt_acnt, palstic) numer, 
             T2.*
        FROM T2
       ORDER BY accnt_acnt, palstic)
SELECT * FROM T3
UNION
SELECT accnt_acnt, palstic, debit, credit FROM T4
 WHERE numer = 1
UNION
SELECT accnt_acnt, palstic, NULL, NULL FROM T4
WHERE numer != 1
```

Comment: Можно. А как определить, какая запись первая? Добавьте оригинальный запрос, структуру таблиц и пример входных данных.

Comment: Проще всего небось через оконные функции будет сделать, то есть PARTITION какой-нибудь

Comment: Даже не первая строка, а любая строка содержала в себе дебит и кредит, а остальные нет. Тоже думаю через partition сделать, пронумеровать своей нумерацией каждый набор с одинаковыми счетами, потом под номером 1 полностью строку забирать, а под остальными делать поля null. Правда пока не получается

Comment: @Евгений Покажите как получилось.

Comment: Охохо я тут такое написал аж смотреть тошно, но вроде работает. Кстати есть способ выбрать все столбцы кроме заданного, не перечисляя их вручную?

Comment: @Евгений Такой вопрос, а не хотите ли вы перенести ответ в вопрос? В ответе запрос как-то "страшно" взглядит, а в вопросе как попытка решения вполне нормально (на то он и вопрос).

Comment: Вы хотите чтоб я ваш ответ скопировал и вставил в свой изначальный вопрос?) Я тут не очень ориентируюсь пока просто.

Comment: @Евгений Мой то зачем!? Ваш конечно. Но это конечно вам решать, т.к. вы автор вопроса.

Comment: Готово, перенес в вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если порядок действительно неважен, то попробуйте так:

```
create table t1 as 
    select 408120001 accno, dbms_random.string ('l',9) card, 125 debit, 60 credit
    from dual connect by level<=3;

select t1.accno, t1.card, t2.debit, t2.credit
from t1
left join (
    select t1.*, rowid, row_number () over (partition by accno order by null) rn 
    from t1) t2 on t2.rowid = t1.rowid and rn = 1;
```

Даст желаемый результат:

```
       ACCNO CARD            DEBIT     CREDIT
------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
   408120001 trlhubnjd         125         60
   408120001 keitngeni                       
   408120001 suirsipcw
```

В `ORDER BY` включите необходимые столбцы, если порядок всё-таки важен.

Comment: У вас выглядит намного симпатичней чем у меня, но и непонятней) Пойду разбираться, огромное вам спасибо вы просто невероятно выручаете

Comment: Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: я даже не знал что при подключении LEFT JOIN можно задать условие как тут rn =1. Получается что в t2 те строки, которые повторяются больше одного раза не существуют и мы как раз их выбираем в select t1.accno, t1.card, t2.debit, t2.credit. Я бы сам никогда до такого не додумался, мощно)

Comment: А как вам моя реализация? Перемудрил, да?)

Comment: @Евгений Да, ваша реализация мне как-то сложной  показалась. Так вы проверили на реальных данных, работает или есть вопросы?

Comment: И то и другое работает, проверил на тестовых) Сейчас ночь, а на работу завтра)))  На работе посмотрим на реальных